# How to delete versioning enabled object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am having trouble deleting objects from S3 buckets. Users are able to download the files, but they are unable to remove them. When I looked at the IAM user privileges, I could see that the user had been granted Get, remove, and List access, and that the object was also subject to versioning. Please advise

Thanks

i want to know the solution for this issue

Comment: Do you want to delete the objects in the console, or via the AWS CLI? If using the console, you first need to 'Show' the versions. Then you can delete a specific version.

Comment: See [Deleting object versions from a versioning-enabled bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DeletingObjectVersions.html).

Answer (score 3):

To delete versioning-enabled objects in AWS S3, the IAM (Identity and Access Management) role associated with the AWS user must have the following necessary permissions.

**s3:DeleteObject** - This permission allows the user to delete the specified object(s).

**s3:DeleteObjectVersion** - This permission allows the user to delete a specific version of an object if you want to delete a specific version instead of the latest version.

If you want to delete all versions of an object (including all previous versions), you may also need the **s3:ListBucketVersions** permission, which allows the user to list all object versions within the bucket.